# Search for string from an array of values, then return the first value it finds as a usable variable outside of the function itself

Tags: php

I'm basically just trying to store or access the found string as usable variable (that can be echo'd outside of this function).

Here's the code for my function;

```
        function strposa($haystack, $needle, $offset=0) 
    {
             if(!is_array($needle)) $needle = array($needle);

             foreach($needle as $query) 
             { 
                    if(stripos($haystack, $query, $offset) !== false) return $query;
             }


             return false;

    }
```

So once it finds a match, how do I then echo out the match in my html using

```
<?php echo $found; ?>
```

Here's an idea of how it's being used....

```
$haystack = 'May contain traces of nuts';
$needle = array('gluten','nuts','milk');

$found = strposa($haystack, $needle, $offset);

if(strposa($haystack, $needle, 0)) {
      echo $found;
};
```

This is currently producing bool(false) using the above function.

Comment: In my case, my $haystack is a string, and my $needles are in an array. The function works perfectly fine, it's just I cannot seem to get the "$found" variable string into my html page.

Comment: Can you offer minimal samples for your variables: `$haystack` and `$needle` and how you are calling this function, so that we can understand your objective and replicate/test?  ... and what you expect to return for the sample case.

Comment: I've edited my original code at top and added an example of exactly how it's being used.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of odd that needle is an array and not haystack, but ignoring that, you have two issues:

First, you need to return the value and not the key:

```
function strposa($haystack, $needle, $offset=0) 
{
    if(!is_array($needle)) $needle = array($needle);

    foreach($needle as $query) 
    { 
        if(stripos($haystack, $query, $offset) !== false) return $query;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Second, you need to assign the return to something:

```
<?php $found = strposa($haystack, $needle, $offset); ?>
<?php echo $found; ?>
```

But since it may be returning `false`, you'll need to test for that in the above assignment or before echoing:

```
if($found = strposa($haystack, $needle, $offset)) {
      echo $found;
}
```

Comment: Adjusted my function to return $query, but still not getting anything out of $found on my page even though the function is working correctly because it's being used within an if statement on my page which is evaluating to "true".

Comment: I just put var_dump($found); on the page and got a bool(false) , so it must be evaluating false then.... hmm.

Comment: You would have to give an example needle and haystack that should match.

Comment: I've edited my original code at top and added an example of exactly how it's being used.

Comment: I see you fixed the needle/needles problem.  Works fine here: https://3v4l.org/KleMT echos `nuts`.

Comment: Yeah noticed that after I posted the code, but still doesn't seem to work for me...

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted where it works?  Find out what is different.

Answer (score 0):

Using [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with piped needles in your case-insensitive regex pattern removes the need for a custom function that uses a loop AND will allow you to better customize your search if/when your terms yield false positives due to the string existing inside of the a larger/different word.

I have displayed 3 working examples.  The first is without an offset and works as expected.  The second is without an offset and highlights a potential pitfall with any string search method.  The third uses an offset and works as expected.

```
$needle = array('gluten','nuts','milk');
$regex="/".implode("|",$needle)."/i";
// $regex = /gluten|nuts|milk/i

$haystack = 'May contain traces of nuts';
if(preg_match($regex,$haystack,$match)){
    $found=$match[0];
}else{
    $found="Not Found"; // false
}
echo "<div>Found = $found</div>";
// TRUE POSITIVE:
// Output: Found = nuts

$haystack = 'This recipe is gluten-free!';
if(preg_match($regex,$haystack,$match)){
    $found=$match[0];
}else{
    $found="Not Found"; // false
}
echo "<div>Found = $found</div>";
// FALSE POSITIVE:
// Output: Found = gluten
// improve your regex pattern as needed
//     for instance use: $regex="/\b".implode("\b|\b",$needle)."\b/i";
//     against $haystack="May contain bits of shell from coconuts";
//     and it will return "Not Found" because of the word boundaries

$haystack = 'Who put nuts in my milk?!';
$offset=12;  // start beyond nuts
if(preg_match($regex,substr($haystack,$offset),$match)){
    $found=$match[0];
}else{
    $found="Not Found"; // false
}
echo "<div>Found = $found</div>";
// TRUE POSITIVE:
// Output: Found = milk
```

Comment: @JasonMorgan If my answer solves your issue please award it the green tick (and possibly an upvote for being helpful).  Otherwise, please explain what is left to accomplish.